# Windows Security popup window pops up each time any connection is made

Tags: windows

I have a problem with the Windows Security popup below. It pops up every time the system tries to make connection with any internet source. It's very annoying, and I don't know how to resolve the problem.

(The popup window below is in Dutch, but says something like *Connect to somedomain.com*. Then it expects you to give your credentials.)

I am running on a Windows 7 x64 OS.

[image: Windows Security popup]

Now how do I solve this problem? Is it a Windows Firewall problem?

Comment: Are you running a proxy server of some sort?

Comment: Please give an example website like Google.com.

Comment: Seems to me more of a [su] problem than [security.se].  I'm recommending migration - please don't cross-post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.

I was connected to LAN with *Obtain IP Address Automatically* option and I was getting problem of "Authentication Required" when I was using my wireless modem to access web sites.

The problem was solved when I changed it to - *Use This IP Address* (i.e. static IP)

Edit

It seems, i was too hasty in posting the solution.

The problem returned back after restarting.

However if i disable LAN connection, i can access web pages without "Authentication Required"

Edit (second)

My problem is solved by turning off Windows 7 Firewall.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are running some proxy. Whenever you send a request it is going through that proxy and which requires authentication. Take a look at your system and browser configurations for networking proxies.

For Internet Explorer:

1. Run `inetcpl.cpl`.
2. Switch to the "Connections" tab.
3. Click the "LAN settings" button.
4. Look to see if there are values (other than "Port: 80") populated in the "Proxy server" section.

If a proxy is configured in IE (most other system components and applications use or copy these settings by default) then you may be having a problem authenticating to it with the currently-logged-on profile.  If not, your problem probably lies elsewhere.

If you're using a different browser or application, see if the problem occurs when using IE.  If it does, then do the check outlined above.  If not, look up how to check proxy settings for your application.

Comment: Fiddler was causing this behavior for me!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to access a website and you are using IE as your browser, do the following: IE>Tools>Internet Options>Security tab>for each zone (Internet, Local intranet, Trusted sites, Restricted sites) click the 'Custom level...' button, scroll to bottom of the window, and make sure that, under 'User Authentication>Logon' that 'Prompt for user name and password' is not checked in any zone. I would also check what sites are listed in each zone. If you see any entries using the * wildcard, most likely that is causing your issue. If this is a domain connected computer, these settings are probably controlled by Group Policy. If not, you can control them locally. I would also check your hosts and lmhosts files (C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc) to make sure there aren't any crazy redirects hidden there. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Change the configuration on Internet Explorer to enable accessing data across domains:

- Open IE

  - Go to Internet Options
  - Under Security tab
  - Select Custom Level
  - Under "Miscelaneous" select "Enable" under "Access data sources across domains"

You might want to change the proxy configuration as well:

- On IE

  - Go to Internet Options
  - Under Connections tab
  - Under LAN settings
  - Unselect Automatically detect settings
  - Also make sure you are not using any proxy server

Comment: It would be nice if people could leave a comment saying why the answer was not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use COMPANY\username and replace 'COMPANY' with the domain name of the site you are logging into.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to run `powershell` then type

```
netsh wlan delete profile <NAME>
```

where `<NAME>` is the name of the offending wifi network, in my case `eduroam`.
Next time I connected, the correct password box was shown.

Answer (score -1):

I fought this same problem for months and finally discovered it is not a Microsoft Windows issue. The problem is with your Email Account. Contact your Internet Service Provider (ISP) Technical Support Department and ask them to Delete your Head/Main Email account due to its corruption on their server and have them create you a new email account. Ask them for the email account POP and SMTP settings to set up your new email account. Then delete your old email account from your Windows Mail or Outlook Mail, etc. and set up your new email account. This is what I had to do to fix the same situation you are having with the Windows Email Security Popup Windows. My Windows email accounts have been working perfectly ever since I did this. Then enjoy your computer once again.

Comment: Not sure how this is a server-side issue. It's likely the changes on the client side that count.

Answer (score -2):

This pops up because (in my case) you want to copy and paste text from one site to another thing (like Microsoft Word). It is harmless and all you do is just type the username and password you use to get in the site and the below thing is "remember my credentials" (so you should never have to do it again, the entering the credentials).

I would just do as it says though.

Comment: This is not good security advice. How do you know something is not intercepting to collect credentials. Any internet source would imply sites that do not require authentication normally.

Comment: well I actually have had it, and if you trust the site, do it, but don't check the box then. I mean, blackboard had to get my credentials when I wish to copy and paste the curriculum into a word doc. Just make sure authenticity is legit, and all is good.

Answer (score -2):

Try to switching the UAC [User Access Control] "OFF" and reconnect to Internet.
the above option is available in Control Panel.
if still the Authentication pops up then it is definitely for Host verification by a Proxy-Server or maybe DHCP Server running on your Network.

Comment: The UAC prompt is a bit different, and generally much more specific, than the dialog displayed here.  Additionally, it should not be engaged simply by attempting access to the Internet.

Comment: Additionally, while this may be a useful troubleshooting option, you should be sure to revert the UAC changes when you're done.